# get position with Map context

Tags: java, list, hashmap, spring-batch

I'm trying to create a custom Itemreader using a HashMap, here is an eaxmple i find it of an itemReader using a list instead of HashMap

```
public class InMemoryStudentReader implements ItemReader<StudentDTO> {

    private int nextStudentIndex;
    private List<StudentDTO> studentData;

    InMemoryStudentReader() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        StudentDTO tony = new StudentDTO();
        tony.setEmailAddress("tony.tester@gmail.com");
        tony.setName("Tony Tester");
        tony.setPurchasedPackage("master");

        StudentDTO nick = new StudentDTO();
        nick.setEmailAddress("nick.newbie@gmail.com");
        nick.setName("Nick Newbie");
        nick.setPurchasedPackage("starter");

        StudentDTO ian = new StudentDTO();
        ian.setEmailAddress("ian.intermediate@gmail.com");
        ian.setName("Ian Intermediate");
        ian.setPurchasedPackage("intermediate");

        studentData = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(tony, nick, ian));
        nextStudentIndex = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public StudentDTO read() throws Exception {
        StudentDTO nextStudent = null;

        if (nextStudentIndex < studentData.size()) {
            nextStudent = studentData.get(nextStudentIndex);
            nextStudentIndex++;
        }

        return nextStudent;
    }
}
```

As you can see here we can iterate on a list by it's position (index), so when we call next time the method read() we garantie that we get the next elment.

But in my case the is no notion of index, as HashMap has no concept of position so there is no way to get an object by position.

haw can update this code to work with my case:

```
   public class InMemoryMouvementReader implements ItemReader<MouvementFileRow> {


        @Autowired
        private MouvementToMap mvts;

        @Override
        public MouvementFileRow read() throws Exception {
            MouvementFileRow nextMouvement = null;


  // the Map
       // public Map<Long, MouvementFileRow> getMouvmentFileRowMap() {
       //     return mouvmentFileRowMap;
     //   }

         mvts.getMouvmentFileRowMap()

            return nextMouvement;
        }
    }
```

do i need to change the hashMap to LinkedHashMap instead or to convert map to List ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no indexes like 0, 1, ... n but you can use the keys in an specific order (e.g. alphabetic sort). Another approach is to get a Iterator object by calling yourHashMap.keySet().iterator() and use that object as class-attribute instead of the nextStudentIndex-attribute. Then use a code snippet like:

```
if (yourIterator.hasNext()) return yourHashMap.get(youtIterator.next());
else return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any kind of index in your implementation, then `read(idx)` can be written in the loop, where `read()` is going to be called idx times.

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation, i can't undrestand what you mean , i thout that the method read will be called eatch time and for all new call i shoud prepare the next index to get the new element

Comment: As I understand you asked "how can I reach some element by its position, without implementing the index?" I didn't even read your code, but when you don't have an access to index, you must start from the beginning of collection and iterate until you reach wanted position. Maybe, I didn't understand you well.